# Uploading an image file from Meteor method using Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, meteor

Using the AWS-SDK package for Meteor, I've successfully set up and connected to Amazon S3 upon starting my app. And I was also able to upload a non-image file using the putObject() method.

```
$s3->putObject(...);
```

However whenever I'm trying to upload an image from , I hit a roadblock. How can I use a Meteor method to get the image from  and upload it to Amazon S3?